# MVC Model returns null to controller after Form POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My Model (CountryContinentModels) is always null after posting a form. 
In my controller I always get model null and I can't seem to find why, I've looked through the code several times, asked around with my class mates and checked several other stack overflow questions & answers, most of the times the issue is related to naming, I don't think this is the case here.
I'm trying to Create a new entry in my database, using the CountryContinent Model (has Country and Continent)

I'm setting up a CRUD, and I'm getting stuck setting up the Create.

Here is the Create view:

```
    @model TransactionImporter.WebUI.Models.CountryContinentModels

    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }

    <h2>Create</h2>


    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CountryContinentModels</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Continent, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Continent, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </div>
        </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Here is the Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TransactionImporter.BLL.Interfaces;
using TransactionImporter.Factory;
using TransactionImporter.WebUI.Models;
using TransactionImpoter.Domain;

namespace TransactionImporter.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class CountryContinentController : Controller
    {
        private ICountryContinentLogic countryContinentLogic = CountryContinentFactory.CreateLogic();

        // GET: CountryContinent/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: CountryContinent/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(CountryContinentModels models)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                CountryContinent countryContinent = new CountryContinent(models.Country, models.Continent);
                countryContinentLogic.AddCountry(countryContinent);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: CountryContinent
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<CountryContinent> countryContinents = countryContinentLogic.GetAllCountries();
            List<CountryContinentModels> countryModels = new List<CountryContinentModels>();
            foreach (CountryContinent country in countryContinents)
            {
                countryModels.Add(new CountryContinentModels(country.Country, country.Continent));
            }

            return View(countryModels);
        }


        // GET: CountryContinent/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            CountryContinent country = new CountryContinent(countryContinentLogic.GetCountryById(id).Country,
                countryContinentLogic.GetCountryById(id).Continent);
            CountryContinentModels model = new CountryContinentModels(country.Country, country.Continent);
            return View(model);
        }

        // POST: CountryContinent/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(CountryContinentModels model, int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                CountryContinent continent = new CountryContinent(model.Country, model.Continent);
                countryContinentLogic.UpdateCountryById(id, continent);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: CountryContinent/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: CountryContinent/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TransactionImporter.WebUI.Models
{
    public class CountryContinentModels
    {
        public CountryContinentModels(string country, string continent)
        {
            Country = country;
            Continent = continent;
        }
        public CountryContinentModels() { }
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        public string Country { get; private set; }
        [Display(Name = "Continent")]
        public string Continent { get; private set; }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any errors / exceptions?

Comment: No, I added a breakpoint to check if the model gets returned properly in the controller but as seen in the screenshot it's null:
https://gyazo.com/0d172281bf52c5e2fbe71c8573a892e7

Comment: That screenshot looks like the parameter coming back is NOT null? It looks like it is saying some properties are returning null.

Comment: Can you remove the private setter to normal setter and see? Lets see if the visibility is what causing the controller not to fill the model ?

Comment: Could you remove the constructor in the model and see if it helps? Usually constructors don't play well with the model binder.

Comment: Looks like it indeed was the private setter causing issues, this is now resolved. Thank you all for the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the model-binding happens, it helps to understand the steps that ASP.NET takes to create the model, specifically:

1. ASP.NET creates an instance of your model using the default constructor.
2. Each property's `set` method is called if there is an HTML input with a matching `name`.

On first look, you'll need to change your properties to have public `set` methods like so:

```
public string Continent { get; set; }
```

That should fix the issue, but if it doesn't, you can check the generated names in the HTML to make sure they make sense relative to the names of your C# properties.

Comment: You sir, are a legend. Thanks a lot. 
It indeed helps to understand what steps ASP.NET takes to create the model, I will be sure to kee this in mind for future debugging. 
This solved my issue, I need to remind myself to keep the setters public in my view models. 
Thanks again!